# Issue with javascript regex not matching less than 3 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following javascript regex:

```
/^[^\s][a-z0-9 ]+[^\s]$/i
```

I need to allow any alphanumeric character as well as spaces inside the string but not at the beginning nor at the end.

Oddly enough, the above regex will not accept less than 3 characters, e.g. `aa` will not match but `aaa` will.

I am not sure why. Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Because you have 3 character classes which will match at least 1 character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should re-write the expression as

```
/^[a-z0-9]+(?:\s+[a-z0-9]+)*$/i
```

See  the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/JlHvbv/2).

NOTE: If only one whitespace is allowed between the alphanumeric chars use

```
/^[a-z0-9]+(?:\s[a-z0-9]+)*$/i
              ^^
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z0-9]+` - 1+ letters/digits
- `(?:\s+[a-z0-9]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of 1+ whitespaces (`\s+`) and 1+ digit/letters
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=i&re=%5E%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B(%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B)*%24):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have: `[^\s]` (requires matching at least one non-whitespace character), `[a-z0-9 ]+` (requires matching at least one alphanumeric or space character), and `[^\s]` again (requires matching at least one non-whitespace character). So, in total, you need at least 3 characters in the string.

Use word boundaries at the beginning and end instead:

```
/^\b[a-z0-9 ]+\b$/i
```

https://regex101.com/r/2GhH3N/1

Answer (score 2):

Try the following regex:

```
^(?! )[a-z0-9 ]*[a-z0-9]$
```

Details:

- `^(?! )` - Start of the string and no space after it (so here we exclude the
  initial space).
- `[a-z0-9 ]*` - A sequence of letters, digits and spaces, possibly empty
  (the content before the last letter(see below).
- `[a-z0-9]$` - The last letter and the end of string (so here we exclude the
  terminal space).